# Excel VBA - runtime error 1004 when simplifying recorded code

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, simplify

I've got a recorded macro that I tried to simplify by getting a number of activate and select statements onto a single line, but that results in a runtime error.

This is not a critical problem, but I'm just curious to understand what is going on. This is my initial code snippet (it is preceded by a Copy snippet in the procedure):

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate  
Sheets("MS Act Report").Select  
Range("G1").Select  
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

this is my simplified code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate  
Sheets("MS Act Report").Range("G1").Select  
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

When running this I get a

> `runtime error '1004': Select method of Range class failed`

Comment: You can only select ranges on the active sheet. If "MS Act Report" is not the active sheet, you can't issue a .select command against its cells.

Comment: You don't need to select anyway: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS Act Report").Range("G1").PasteSpecial`

Comment: @vacip - thanks. So by using the separate select commands the sheet becomes activated but this is not the case if I have it on one line.

Comment: @Rory - thanks. I'd tried something like your suggestion previously but used   .Paste instead of   .PasteSpecial, which didn't work. Do you know why that is? Thanks for your suggestion. Going with that one!

Comment: @doterfish Exactly, using them step by step they get activated one after the other. For the other question, .Paste is a method of the Worksheet object, .PasteSpecial is a method of the Range object (so you have to use SomeWorksheet.Paste or SomeRange.PasteSpecial. No other way, can't mix them). As for the why: because. Because someone at Microsoft decided this will work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only select ranges on the active sheet. If "MS Act Report" is not the active sheet, you can't issue a .select command against its cells. To simplify the code, instead of copy-pasting, just make the ranges equal.

```
Thisworkbook.WorkSheets("MS Act Report").Range("G1:I5").Value= _
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Whatever").Range("a1:c5").Value
```

Some recommended reading: [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but the range that's copied is different everytime the procedure is run, so I'd need to work around that. So Rory's suggestion above seems more straightforward.